# how to delete or drop database when I missing physical data

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I have database with name music
I can Not work on database

I can not drop my database ,because I Get this  Error (dbcc checkdb)

The operating system returned error 21(The device is not ready.) to SQL Server during a read at offset 0x000000277e2000 in file 'Edb-back\music.mdf'. Additional messages in the SQL Server error log and operating system error log may provide more detail

I Can not do any thing likely (restore , delete , rename ,single user mode ,...)
I want delete from my SQL server

What should I do?

Comment: Did you try tsql command like "drop database db_name"

Comment: yes i did but i get this error : to SQL Server during a read at offset 0x000000277e2000

Comment: What do you mean *missing physical data*?...do the .MDF / .LDF files no longer exist, but it's still showing in the list of databases?

Comment: I would start trying to hunt down the files on disk, if they exist. My guess is that they do, and SQL server try to access those file which fails based on some physical issue. If the files don't exist in the first place, then methink that the DROP will just remove the database meta-data from SQL Server.

Comment: I Lost MDF file

Comment: change type my mdf file to MDF but it should be SQL server primary data file

Comment: Do you see the file location in sys.master_files? What is the status of DB? Did you try detach?

Comment: yes I see in sys.master_files but I can not Detach database and The database name is still in sql how can i drop database name or delete ?
Whatever I do, I get this error

Comment: See [The operating system returned error 21](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/165816/the-operating-system-returned-error-21-the-device-is-not-ready) as it might be related to your problem. Is the database on server or desktop? Is the disk a local disk or a share on the network?

Comment: I restart my machine and every thing be ok